# How to check if element is HTMLElement in template Angular?

Tags: angular, angular8

I tried to check if element is HTML element:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of links">

   if (link instanceof HTMLElement) {
      // ADD HERE IN TEMPLATE  
   } else {
       // USE DEFAULT
       {{item.link}}

   }   

</div>
```

How to do this properly using Angular?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Comment: How to insert `HTMLElement` on the page in loop?

Comment: Seems I SHOULD USE  [innerHTML]

Comment: what about custom pipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this

**component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of links">
   <div *ngIf="checkData(item)">
       <div [innerHTML]="item"></div>
   </div>
   <div *ngIf="!checkData(item)">
       <div [innerHTML]="item"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**conmponent.ts**

```
checkData(link) {
 if (link instanceof HTMLElement) {
      reuturn true;
   } else {
       return false;
   }   
}
```